# Method inside a non renderd JSF panel is still called

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

In the code below when `#{bean.renderPanel1}` evaluates to false the method in the ui:repeat is still called.

1. Is this the expected behavior?
2. Is there a way to prevent this call from happening. For example, using something other than `h:panelGroup` but not `c:if`

```
<h:panelGroup id="panel1" rendered="#{bean.renderPanel1}">      
  <ui:repeat value="#{bean.panelOneItems}" var="item">                                  

  </ui:repeat>                  
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *In the code below when #{bean.renderPanel1} evaluates to true the method in the ui:repeat is still called.*

Yes, this is fully expected behaviour. It will only not be called when the rendered attribute evaluates to `false`.

Comment: I had a typo in my question which I edited. I meant to say that I tested and "#{bean.panelOneItems}" is called even when "#{bean.renderPanel1}" is false. Is this expected?

Comment: No. What JSF impl/version are you using then?

Comment: Good to know that methods inside a non rendered panel shouldn't be called. I'll look to see if there's an issue in the Mojarra version I'm using